# Javascript regexp that matches specific letter combinations with number range

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like a javascript regexp that only matches these strings:

"xs1"
"xs2"
"xs3"
... etc all the way to "xs24"

"s1"
"s2"
"s3"
... etc all the way to "s24"

"m1"
"m2"
"m3"
... etc all the way to "m24"

"l1"
"l2"
"l3"
... etc all the way to "l24"

"xl1"
"xl2"
"xl3"
... etc all the way to "xl24"

E.g. "xs20" should return true, but "xs0" and "xs25" should return false.

I tried

```
/^(xs|s|m|l|xl)[1-24]$/
```

but that's not workings as I want because "xs24" returns false

Comment: +1 This question shows a good effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with

```
/^(xs|s|m|l|xl)[1-24]$/
```

except that `[1-24]` would match the range from `1` to `2`, or the character `4`. Instead, you need:

```
/^(xs|s|m|l|xl)(1?[1-9]|10|2[0-4])$/
```

This will match the characters from `1` to `9` with or without a `1` prefixing them, `10`, or `2` followed by a number from 0 to 4.

Comment: `[1-24]` does not match `-` because it is a range between 1 and 2 it matches `1` `2` and `4`

Comment: /^(xs|s|m|l|xl)(1?\d|2[0-4])$/.test("xs0") returns true. Only a number from 1-24 should return true.

Comment: @AdrianRosca Updated (although starting to look a little messy now - there may be a neater way).

Comment: `/^(xs|s|m|l|xl)([1-9]|1\d|2[0-4])$/` would look a bit cleaner to me.

Comment: @AdrianWragg That's it! Works just like I intended. Thanx =)

Comment: @AdrianRosca, how are you creating the regex? If you use the new operator you need to double escape `/^(xs|s|m|l|xl)([1-9]|1\\d|2[0-4])$/`

Comment: @AdrianRosca `/^(xs|s|m|l|xl)(?!0)(1?\d|2[0-4])$/` is another way; the `(?!0)` stops the next part matching just the `0`. I can update the answer with this if it's clearer, and add an explanation - it is the shortest suggestion, at any rate.

Comment: @AdrianWragg I would say the current one without !? is clearer

Comment: @AdrianRosca Fair enough, will leave it just in the comment; only checking because you'd already accepted the original.